# How to search document and change specify characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I search for a vba code to do something and found nothing. 
I like to:

1. Specify 2 characters by a inputbox. For example SearchBox=ChrW(1820) and ReplaceBox=ChrW(0710)
2. Search the document and get the first word and the first character of this word.
3. If first character is specified in SearchBox then

   a. check if in this word exist characters = ChrW(1820) or ChrW(1821) or ChrW(1820)

   b. if first character = exist characters then

   c. change first character with other one specified in ReplaceBox

   d. else: do nothing
4. Go to next word and check the same (looping)
5. Finish the document and message "50 characters changed"

I know its a lite confusion but I'm here to give your explanations. So please HELP.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution for my answer:

```
For Each w In ActiveDocument.Words
    If Left(w, 1) = "a" Then 'Check if words start with "a" then
       'Check if exist letters "a" or "b" after first character then
        If InStr(2, w, "a") Or InStr(2, w, "b") Then w.Text = "A" & Mid(w, 2) 
           'Change the first Character with "A"
    End If
Next
```

But now i can't do the same for last two characters of words.
I have test:

```
If Right(w, 2) = "au" Then
 If InStr(2, w, "a") Then w.Text = "AU" & Right(w, 2)
```

But not working. Any solution please?

And one more...how to make `Else` before `End If`  because i have problem. When i make `Else` i have error `"End If without If"`